# Add a fill pattern to feature style instead of a fill color on a certain condition in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, style, fill

As a continuation to [Hatch polygons in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420564/hatch-polygons-in-leaflet)

I'm using Vue and Quasar but I would love to see any type of example.  What I have is

```
statestyleCDC(feature) {
   return {
        fillColor: this.getColorBrewerCDC(county[""number]),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };



 getColorBrewerCDC(){


if( d == "*"){
  return "#f9f9f9" //Want a fillPattern //  
}

//
  if (typeof d == 'undefined') {
         return "#66c2a4"
          }
          return d >=  (this.colorGrades[4])
          ? this.colorGroup[4]
          : d >=  (this.colorGrades[3])
          ? this.colorGroup[3]
          : d >=  (this.colorGrades[2])
          ? this.colorGroup[2]
          : d >=  this.colorGrades[1]
          ?  this.colorGroup[1]
          : d >=  this.colorGrades[0]
          ? this.colorGroup[0]
          : "#000";
```

}

What I want to do is if d= "*" then provide a fill pattern:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to remove from GeoJSON group layer those layers that require pattern fill and then add corresponding pattern filled polygons, using `leaflet-polygon-fillPattern` Leaflet plugin (http://lwsu.github.io/leaflet-polygon-fillPattern/).

If we take some simple svg pattern image `tiny-hatch.svg` that looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="8" viewBox="0 0 8 8"  shape-rendering="crispEdges">
  <line x1="0" y1="8" x2="8" y2="0" style="stroke: #AAAAAA; stroke-width: 1;" />
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="8" y2="8" style="stroke: #AAAAAA; stroke-width: 1;" />
</svg>
```

then for official Leaflet choropleth example at https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html relevant part of the code could then be:

```
geojson.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  if ((layer.feature.properties.density > 10) && (layer.feature.properties.density < 30)) {
    var coords = layer.getLatLngs();
    var poly = L.polygon(coords, {
      fill:'url(img/tiny-hatch.svg)',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      fillColor: 'white',
      color: '#AAAAAA',
      weight: 1
    }).addTo(geojson);
    geojson.removeLayer(layer);
  }
});
```

and result would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks-- I'll give that a try

Comment: Having any success?